# TenantDb in Azure AD - authentication and Sign-On

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, multi-tenant

We have implemented Sign-On for our MVC application which authenticates users with Azure Active Directory. Since we've used VS2013 templates to do so, we have TenantDbContext (entity framework) to work with Tenant database. We prefer to have only 1 db for our application instead of two.

Is that a good idea to move all of the tables from TenantDB to our application database and update DatabaseIssuerNameRegistry to use our own EF? Anyone had any issues doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Combining TenantDB with main application database and updating EF went well. The only difference was that had to switch class to dynamic instead of static since we are using dynamic connection strings.